# Rails regex: Groups inside groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am trying to to extract a name from two possible strings.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.darkthrone.com/recruiter/outside/B7OE4OA0OD8OD5OF1'))

reg = /([a-zA-Z0-9_]*) has recruited too many people today.|You are being recruited into the army of ([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/

puts doc.text.match(reg).to_s.gsub(reg,"\\1")

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.darkthrone.com/recruiter/outside/B7OD8OE6OC2OF9OD5'))

puts doc.text.match(reg).to_s.gsub(reg,"\\2")
```

I would like to access the `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with the the same group.

Comment: It's very not clear what is your question about. Try maybe providing some expected input/output or maybe provide pseudocode of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to do, and I don't know if it's possible unless Ruby supports named groups. Possibly not even then, since you'd need to give both groups the same name. Are you sure they need to be in the same group?

Comment: Thanks but I got around it with `scan()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in .NET like this:

```
(\w*)(?:(?= has recruited too many people today\.)|(?<=You are being recruited into the army of \1))
```

But I don't think this will work in Ruby since it requires indefinite repetition inside lookbehind. Perhaps you could give it a try?